# Main effects significant but no significant interaction

Tags: hypothesis-testing, reporting

My hypothesis for my dissertation was to find an interaction between two predictors; however, my results showed that the interaction was not significant but the main effects were significant.

In my discussion section would I say that my results did not support my hypothesis and then say that my main effects were significant and then discuss the findings for the main effects accordingly/relate to previous research even if this wasn't my intended hypothesis? Or should my discussion be more focused on the fact that I did not find a significant interaction?

Just looking for some clarity for what a discussion section would look like based on these results.

Comment: "Find significant interaction" is not a proper hypothesis. Maybe you meant "There is an interaction"?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant

Comment: Perhaps your supervisor who is paid to teach and support their students might be worth asking.  If you have and are unsure about their advice then please post what they have said and your concerns so it can be critiqued.

Answer (score 4):

If your only hypothesis was that there would be an interaction, you should concentrate on that in your write up. But 1) You can mention the main effects and 2) You can discuss non-significant interactions (although some committee members may disagree). The interaction has an effect size. If it is far from 0 then that means something, even if it is not significant.